# How to convert utf-8 to cp1252 in C#?

Tags: c#, android, mono

I need to convert a XML file that is being sent on utf-8 to cp1252. How is this possible?

My consumer application only support ANSI characters in it's controls and not Unicode. It also does a memcopy of the bytes received.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work, I get an exception: 11-08 16:38:37.150: I/mono-stdout(15426): System.NotSupportedException: CodePage 1252 not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an anwser from jonp from TEAM XAMARIN - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/337/how-to-send-byte-encoded-as-ansi

It turns out "You need to add the West internationalization assemblies to your application.":

> By default, Mono for Android only includes a limited list of collation
>   tables and Encodings. In order to include additional data into your
>   application, you can use the MandroidI18n property:
>   West

Answer (score 1):

Try the Encoding.Convert method. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Does not work it throws an exception:11-08 16:38:37.150: I/mono-stdout(15426): System.NotSupportedException: CodePage 1252 not supported

Comment: You're using the mono implementation of C#?

Comment: yes, I have to use it since the App runs on Android. My Server App is C# mono for android and my Client App is a C++ MoSync App

Comment: I am not familiar with the Android SDK at all, or how it may change some of the functionality provided by the Microsoft implementation of C#. I retagged your question but I suggest you update your question with some more details so someone with more experience can comment.